# Problem installing Ubuntu in my new computer

Tags: 11.10, installation, nvidia, nouveau

I have a new computer with an Nvidia graphics card and I'm trying to install Ubuntu. Any version newer than Natty will freeze in this state:

[image]

This case is me trying to install 11.10.

Whats weird is that Natty works just fine! What could I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. Starting the installtion in nomodeset. Aparently its an issue with NVIDIA cards.